# View apt-history well-arranged

Tags: apt, package-management

When I look at the apt install history at `/var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz`, there is a lot of information and it is hard to figure out what was installed explicitly and what was brought in as a dependency.

How can I see which packages were explicitly installed (excluding dependencies) by the administrator after the initial standard setup was finished?

(I want to find out, what my collegue did on our server)

Comment: Tried `grep`? http://askubuntu.com/a/337006/158442

Comment: I tried to clarify what you want but I may be wrong. Do you only want those packages that were installed during installation? Only those that were explicitly installed (excluding dependencies)? All packages that were explicitly installed? Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: I found [instructions for Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/464748/34298) using a `manifest` file with all packages installed initially, so I would only need a manifest for jessie to try that.

Comment: @muru your solution with grep will display all packages. I can sort out some libs with `grep 'install ' /var/log/dpkg.log.1 |grep -v -e "\blib"` but still far too much